# Return multiple attributes SQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that consists of the following values

```
Quantity:   ProductID:   ShopID:   ProductName:   ShopName:   Cost:     ...
  3            1          3          Banana       WalStar     3.00      -  
  1            6          2          Pear         Costcut     2.50      -
  4            1          8          Orange       HWBS        0.70      - 
  ...
```

and so forth. There are many repeated Product.Id's shop.Id's etc.

I'm having trouble writing a single query in mySQL to

Find the shop name that has sold more than n items with which one of those items was a Orange.

---

Edit:
These were joined from many tables so far I have

```
SELECT *
#Table Joins
WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM Sale WHERE ProductName = "Orange" GROUP BY ShopID HAVING SUM(DISTINCT Quantity) > 5);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the more than n times

Comment: How could you relate the quantity and productId and find the quantity sold off one product?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ShopID 
FROM Sale 
GROUP BY ShopID 
HAVING SUM(Quantity) > 5
AND SUM(ProductName = 'Orange') > 0
```

Fiddle demo [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0399/13)

Comment: Fixed typo and added the demo. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Never thought it was this simple. I've been browsing stack for the past hour trying to find a solution and most of the nearly relevant ones involved using many nested selects and wheres.